# Google Maps Polygon rendering bug?

Tags: google-maps

For some reason (export import of rectangle shape), I have a polygon rendering a straight rectangle using geodesic lines. The rectangle is filled in with intermediate points to make sure it follows the circles of latitude, as my polygons are always geodesic.
The rendering in Google Maps for this special case is very strange, as if there was some optimisation involved not handling very well the consecutive points with equal latitudes. I attached an example.

Anyone has had this issue before?

[image]

The actual coordinates in lat, long and degrees:

40.4108, -15.3394; 40.4108, -14.3507; 40.4108, -13.3591; 40.4108, -12.3647; 40.4108, -11.3679; 40.4108, -10.3689; 40.4108, -9.3680; 40.4108, -8.3653; 40.4108, -7.3612; 40.4108, -6.3559; 40.4108, -5.3497; 40.4108, -4.3428; 40.4108, -3.3355; 40.4108, -2.3280; 40.4108, -1.3207; 40.4108, -0.3138; 40.4108, 0.6924; 40.4108, 1.6977; 40.4108, 2.7018; 40.4108, 3.7045; 40.4108, 4.7054; 40.4108, 5.7044; 40.4108, 6.7012; 40.4108, 7.6955; 40.4108, 8.6872; 40.4108, 9.6759; 39.3435, 9.6759; 38.2760, 9.6759; 37.2082, 9.6759; 36.1401, 9.6759; 35.0718, 9.6759; 34.0032, 9.6759; 32.9344, 9.6759; 31.8654, 9.6759; 30.7961, 9.6759; 29.7266, 9.6759; 29.7266, 8.6823; 29.7266, 7.6869; 29.7266, 6.6900; 29.7266, 5.6916; 29.7266, 4.6920; 29.7266, 3.6911; 29.7266, 2.6893; 29.7266, 1.6866; 29.7266, 0.6833; 29.7266, -0.3206; 29.7266, -1.3249; 29.7266, -2.3295; 29.7266, -3.3341; 29.7266, -4.3386; 29.7266, -5.3429; 29.7266, -6.3468; 29.7266, -7.3502; 29.7266, -8.3528; 29.7266, -9.3547; 29.7266, -10.3555; 29.7266, -11.3551; 29.7266, -12.3535; 29.7266, -13.3504; 29.7266, -14.3458; 29.7266, -15.3394; 30.7961, -15.3394; 31.8654, -15.3394; 32.9344, -15.3394; 34.0032, -15.3394; 35.0718, -15.3394; 36.1401, -15.3394; 37.2082, -15.3394; 38.2760, -15.3394; 39.3435, -15.3394; 40.4108, -15.3394;

Edit: Check the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leforthomas/UgddA/
Code:

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({geodesic: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      map: map, path: path});
```

You can clearly say that the rectangle is broken, with even a discontinuity. It feels like a bug for Google Maps, but may be there is something I overlooked.

I REPEAT, question is "has anybody had this issue before?".

Comment: FYI: the first point (40.4108, -15.3394) is set as (40.4108, -15.339400000000069) using `google.maps.LatLng()` function.

Comment: What is the problem? What does _your_ code look like?

Comment: Edited the question to add a code example